# Do we need to close file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm running `file_get_contents()` inside a loop, I see a lot of files opened in the Apache log. I don't know the reason behind it. Do we need to close the `file_get_contents()` function after each read?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` reads a file and closes the file afterwards. It returns the read data or `false`, so you have no file handle to use with an `fclose()`, anyway.