# Prevent PHP HTTP wrapper from waiting for close of persistent connection

Tags: php, http, http-headers, keep-alive

I'm using PHP code to retrieve a resource from an HTTP server via [PHP HTTP wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), like:

```
file_get_contents("http://...");
```

While the PHP sends HTTP/1.0 request, the server responds with HTTP/1.1 response with `Connection: Keep-Alive` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: ...
```

Although the PHP has no way to use the persistent connection, it seems to pointlessly wait for the HTTP connection to close. The server closes it only after 60 seconds of inactivity.

---

Is there any way to prevent PHP HTTP wrapper from waiting for the server to close the connection, but close it itself after receiving the data announced by `Content-Length` header?

Or is it at least safe to use the `fopen` and the `fread` loop, reading until I get the `Content-Length` bytes?

---

The only workaround I've found is to set the `timeout` [HTTP context option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to reduce the wait time. But obviously I need to set the timeout high enough to be sure it does not interrupt reading of the response, so it's still far from ideal.

---

Other approaches I've tried without success:

- use the HTTP/1.1 (using the `protocol_version` context option), hoping that it will make PHP be aware of persisted connection
- use the `Connection: close` header (the server ignores it)

Comment: I would suggest curl. If the server is not playing nice and file_get_contents does not use Content-Length, how can it work?

Comment: @SH- I was hoping there's an (context) option to make it working. Or another simple implementation, maybe using `fopen` + `fread` with an explicit use of the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Yah, I took a look at Docs, didn't see anything. Unless there is a hidden param in the source... As for simple, the docs suggest socket I/O...

Comment: Nevermind, fclose won't work with file_get_contents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650817/do-we-need-to-close-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems to be no way to make `get_file_contents` follow `Content-Length` header, I ended up using own implementation:

```
// parse $http_response_header auto variable to associative array
function get_http_response_headers($http_response_header)
{
    $response_headers = array();
    if (isset($http_response_header))
    {
        foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
        {
            $i = strpos($header, ":");
            if ($i !== false)
            {
                $name = trim(substr($header, 0, $i));
                $value = trim(substr($header, $i+1));
            }
            else
            {
                $name = trim($header);
                $value = NULL;
            }
            $name = strtolower($name);
            $response_headers[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response_headers = array();
    }

    return $response_headers;
}

// Replacement for file_get_contents that follows Content-Length header
function http_get_contents($url, $context)
{
    $h = fopen($url, "r", false, $context);
    $result = ($h !== false);
    if ($result)
    {
        $response_headers = get_http_response_headers($http_response_header);

        $len = null;
        // If it is not persistent connection, just read to the end,
        // as file_get_contents does
        if (isset($response_headers["connection"]) &&
            (strcasecmp($response_headers["connection"], "close") == 0))
        {
            $len = false;
        }
        // If it is not persistent connection, follow Content-Length
        else if (isset($response_headers["content-length"]))
        {
            $len = intval($response_headers["content-length"]);
        }
        else
        {
            trigger_error("No Content-Length or Connection:close header");
            $result = false;
        }

        if ($result)
        {
            $result = null;
            $total = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                $toread = ($len === false) ? 16384 : ($len - $total);
                $buf = fread($h, $toread);
                if ($buf === false)
                {
                    trigger_error("Reading HTTP failed");
                    $result = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    $read = strlen($buf);
                    $total += $read;
                    $result .= $buf;
                    if ($len !== false)
                    {
                        if ($read > $len)
                        {
                            trigger_error("Read too much data $read > $len");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if ($read == $len)
                        {
                            // done
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ($read == 0)
                        {
                            // done
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($h);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>"Connection: close\r\n")));
file_get_contents("http://...",false,$context);
```

You say you've done this in which case a better answer may be to manually write/read the response using fsockopen until fgets returns false (don't use feof it'll hang until the connection is closed).

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

EDIT:
As stated previously and after further testing I've confirmed this indeed hangs as well so here's a revised solution that works correctly

```
<?php
$handle = fsockopen("google.com", 80);
if ($handle) {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: google.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $out);

    $bytesread = 0;
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if(strpos($buffer, "Content-Length:") !== false) {
                list(, $len) = explode("Content-Length: ", $buffer);
        }

        if($buffer === "\r\n") {
                break;
        }
    }

    $data = '';
    while($bytesread != intval($len)) {
        $buf = fgets($handle, 1024);
        $bytesread += strlen($buf);
        $data .= $buf;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print $data;
}
?>
```

This is clearly very simple and missing quite a bit of error checking but provides the intended behavior.

Comment: But would the `fgets` really return false in this case? I doubt so. I'd assume the `file_get_contents` does this internally (probably using `fread`-like call instead of `fgets`).

Comment: Appears you're correct on that, better way would be to read the content-length and close at that point. Give me a bit and I'll throw up an example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it. Though wouldn't it be easier to implement using `fopen`, `$http_response_header` and `fread` loop? As I assume that your solution would have to deal with `Content-Encoding` (e.g. chunked). While `fopen`/`fread` should give you decoded data.

Comment: That's another possible solution, it's been a while since I've had to use fopen for this type of situation, I seem to remember similar issues with chunked requests.


EDIT: BUT it appears it's been resolved as of PHP 5.3 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42445