# php file_get_contents when does connection close?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

So I understand that file_get_contents will call fclose() once it receives the response. However what if the response is never recieved? Will php's default timeout handle the timeout response and close the connection or will the connection stay open? If the connection is kept open how can I ensure that the connection is closed? or am I better off using cURL?

Comment: curl is always better than file_get_contents as it is safer comparatively to it.

Comment: Agreed, I thought twice about putting that in the question. What I really want to know though is how file_get_contents handles this.

Comment: found a question similar to yours, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650817/do-we-need-to-close-file-get-contents

Comment: This is handled with `stream_context_create`http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php and http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php with `timeout`

Comment: You can investigate the source code: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/file.c :)

Comment: No it will return false after the `default_socket_timeout` or the `timeout` that you set with the stream context is hit which does not effect the `max_execution_time`, chances are something will be returned unless you are hitting a server that is processing something before it returns anything.

Comment: Thank you @cmorrissey .  I think I am correct in that file_get_contents uses stream_context_create which can be passed a timeout argument that defaults to php.ini timeout if not set.

Comment: @AndrewCoder Thanks for the awesome link. Looks like in the source code the stream is closed no matter what and the response is passed off to be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` uses a regular [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) that you can even pass as 3rd parameter. You can either set a [timeout option](http://php.net/manual/de/context.http.php#context.http.timeout) there.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create([
    'http' ['timeout' => 10]
]);

$content = file_get_contents('http://...', FALSE, $ctx);
```

When you do not specify a `http.timeout` context setting, it will default to the `default_socket_timeout` php.ini setting (which is set to 60 seconds on most systems by default).

Comment: Thanks to Andrew coder in the questions comments that provided a link to the source I was able to determine that the connection stream is closed every time which can be invoked by a timeout that is provided in your answer. Thanks!